# Simple PostgreSQL function to return rows

Tags: postgresql, function, stored-procedures, types

How do I convert a simple select query like `select * from customers` into a stored procedure / function in pg?

I'm new to Postgres and `create function customers() as returns table/setof` just didn't feel right and thus the question here.

I understand procs are called "functions" in pg land. Thus <strike>`create procedure`</strike> does not exist and my only options are to either create a view or a function. The issue is `create function x() returns setof y` returns a paren'd comma separated row of values which can't be used without further processing (at least that's what I'm seeing in pgAdmin and Ruby/Sequel).

`create function x() returns table(...)` requires I embed the row definition which I don't want to.

I'm sure there's a reason behind all this but I'm surprised that the most common use case is this tricky.

Comment: @rebnoob Rather than "didn't work" - specify **the full text of the function you tried and the resulting error message** as well as your PostgreSQL version.

Comment: Great! Thank you Erwin and Craig.

Comment: So is this question answered properly?

Answer (score 21):

Untested but should be about right:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getcustomers() RETURNS SETOF customers AS $$
SELECT * FROM customers;
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

Comment: this works, thank you. But pg seems to return just one column with comma sep'd values instead of actual columns, what gives?

Comment: @rebnoob You're calling it with something like `SELECT x FROM getcustomers() x`. You want to use `SELECT getcustomers();` or `SELECT * FROM getcustomers();`.

Answer (score 19):

> The issue is "create function x() returns setof y" returns a paren'd
> comma separated row values which can't be used without further processing

The function returns a row. To decompose into individual columns, call it with:

```
SELECT * FROM getcustomers();
```

That's assuming the function defines a proper return type. See:

- [How to return multiple rows from PL/pgSQL function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17244256/how-to-return-multiple-rows-from-pl-pgsql-function/17281457#17281457)

The [manual on `CREATE FUNCTION`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html) should be a good starting point. The example section covers this topic.

Comment: You sir.. are a jedi and force to reckon with!

Comment: Wasted 1 day to understand what was the problem. I was calling function without " * from" part and EF Core was giving error about db model mapping. Because data was comma, separated. Thanks :)

Comment: I get this `a column definition list is required for functions returning "record"`

Comment: @TheRealChx101: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17281457/939860