# How to return multiple rows from PL/pgSQL function?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have spent good amount of time trying to figure it out and I haven't been able to resolve it. So, I need your help please.

I am trying to write a PL/pgSQL function that returns multiple rows. The function I wrote is shown below. But it is not working.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_object_fields()
RETURNS SETOF RECORD
AS 
$$
DECLARE result_record keyMetrics;
BEGIN
    return QUERY SELECT department_id into result_record.visits 
    from fact_department_daily 
    where report_date='2013-06-07';
    --return result_record;
END

$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql; 

SELECT * FROM get_object_fields;
```

It is returning this error:

> ERROR:  RETURN cannot have a parameter in function returning set;
>   use RETURN NEXT at or near "QUERY"

Comment: As always, your version of Postgres is an essential detail.

Comment: This question is answered on [stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/186350/91706)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see more bugs:

first, a SET RETURNING FUNCTIONS call has following syntax

```
SELECT * FROM get_object_fields()
```

second - RETURN QUERY forwards query result to output directly. You cannot store this result to variable - it is not possible ever in PostgreSQL now.

```
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY SELECT ....; -- result is forwarded to output directly
  RETURN;   -- there will not be any next result, finish execution
END;
```

third - these simple functions is better to implement in SQL languages

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_object_fields()
RETURNS SETOF RECORD AS $$
SELECT department_id WHERE ...
$$ LANGUAGE sql STABLE;
```

Answer (score 21):

After fixing the bugs [@Pavel pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17275419/939860), also define your **return type** properly, or you have to provide a column definition list with every call.

This call:

```
SELECT * FROM get_object_fields()
```

... assumes that Postgres knows how to expand **`*`**. Since you are returning anonymous records, you get an exception:

```
ERROR:  a column definition list is required for functions returning "record"
```

One way (of several) to fix this is with `RETURNS TABLE` (Postgres 8.4+):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_object_fields()
  RETURNS TABLE (department_id int) AS 
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY
   SELECT department_id
   FROM   fact_department_daily 
   WHERE  report_date = '2013-06-07';
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Works for SQL functions just the same.

Related:

- [PostgreSQL: ERROR: 42601: a column definition list is required for functions returning "record"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605174/postgresql-error-42601-a-column-definition-list-is-required-for-functions-ret/8611675#8611675)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way

```
drop function if exists get_test_type();

drop type if exists test_comp;
drop type if exists test_type;
drop type if exists test_person;

create type test_type as (
  foo int, 
  bar int
);

create type test_person as (
  first_name text, 
  last_name text
);

create type test_comp as 
(
  prop_a test_type[], 
  prop_b test_person[]
);


create or replace function get_test_type()
returns test_comp
as $$
declare
  a test_type[];
  b test_person[];
  x test_comp;
begin

  a := array(
    select row (m.message_id, m.message_id) 
    from message m
  );

  -- alternative 'strongly typed'
  b := array[
    row('Bob', 'Jones')::test_person,
    row('Mike', 'Reid')::test_person
  ]::test_person[];

  -- alternative 'loosely typed'
  b := array[
    row('Bob', 'Jones'),
    row('Mike', 'Reid')
  ];

  -- using a select
  b := array (
    select row ('Jake', 'Scott')
    union all 
    select row ('Suraksha', 'Setty')
  );  

  x := row(a, b);

  return x;  
end;
$$
language 'plpgsql' stable;


select * from get_test_type();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_object_fields()
RETURNS table (department_id integer)
AS 
$$
DECLARE result_record keyMetrics;
BEGIN
    return QUERY 
SELECT department_id 
    from fact_department_daily 
    where report_date='2013-06-07';
    --return result_record;
END;

$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql; 

SELECT * FROM get_object_fields()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).