# plpgsql : how to reference variable in sql statement

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am rather new to PL/pgSQL and don't know how to reference a variable in a `SELECT` statement.

In this following function the `SELECT INTO` always returns `NULL`:

```
$body$
DECLARE
 r RECORD;
 c CURSOR FOR select name from t_people;
 nb_bills integer;
BEGIN
 OPEN c;
 LOOP
   FETCH c INTO r;
   EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;

   RAISE NOTICE 'name found: %', r.name; 
   SELECT count(bill_id) INTO nb_bills from t_bills where name = r.name;
 END LOOP;

END;
$body$
```

`RAISE NOTICE` allows me to verify that my `CURSOR` is working well: names are properly retrieved, but for some reason still unknown to me, not properly passed to the `SELECT INTO` statement.

For debugging purpose, I tried to replace the variable in `SELECT INTO` with a constant value and it worked:

```
SELECT count( bill_id) INTO nb_bills from t_bills where name = 'joe';
```

I don't know how to reference `r.name` in the `SELECT INTO` statement. 
I tried `r.name`, I tried to create another variable containing quotes, it is always returning `NULL`.
I am stuck. If anyone knows ...

Comment: The reference `r.name` is correct. When you run `select p.name, count(b.bill_id) from t_people p join t_bills b on t.name = b.name group by name` in a SQL client, what does it return?

Comment: Where and how you are checking `nb_bills` value? Show whole code if it possible.

Comment: The ***header*** showing `IN` and `OUT` parameters, RETURN type, language declaration etc. is an essential part of the function. Remember to always include it - as well as your ***version*** of Postgres.

Comment: Hi an thanks for your reply. 
What I mean to say is the following:

   -- r.name contains 'joe'   
   SELECT count(bill_id) INTO nb_bills from t_bills where name = r.name;
   RAISE NOTICE 'nb_bills: %', nb_bills; -- shows NULL

but
   
   SELECT count(bill_id) INTO nb_bills from t_bills where name = 'joe';
   RAISE NOTICE 'nb_bills: %', nb_bills; -- shows 5

Is there a way I could see the SQL query submitted ? I tried to activate the log feature but it does seem not show this kind of SQL statement. Only call to the procedure is logged.

Answer (score 0):

> the `SELECT INTO` always returns NULL

> not properly passed to the `SELECT INTO` statement.

> it is always returning NULL.

None of this makes sense.

`SELECT` statements do not ***return*** anything by itself in PL/pgSQL. You have to either assign results to variables or explicitly return results with one of the available `RETURN` variants.

`SELECT INTO` is *only* used for variable assignment and does not return anything, either. Not to be confused with `SELECT INTO` in plain SQL - which is generally discouraged:

- [Combine two tables into a new one so that select rows from the other one are ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15559090/combine-two-tables-into-a-new-one-so-that-select-rows-from-the-other-one-are-ign/15560009#15560009)

It's not clear what's supposed to be returned in your example. You did not disclose the return type of the function and you did not actually return anything.

Start by reading the chapter [**Returning From a Function**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING) in the manual.
Here are some related answers with examples:

- [Can I make a plpgsql function return an integer without using a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169676/can-i-make-a-plpgsql-function-return-an-integer-without-using-a-variable/8169928#8169928)
- [Return a query from a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7548292/return-a-query-from-a-function/7548734#7548734)
- [How to return multiple rows from PL/pgSQL function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17244256/how-to-return-multiple-rows-from-pl-pgsql-function/17281457#17281457)
- [Return setof record (virtual table) from function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/955167/return-setof-record-virtual-table-from-function/17247118#17247118)

And there may be naming conflicts with parameter names. We can't tell unless you post the complete function definition.

#### Better approach

That said, explicit cursors are only actually needed on rare occasions. Typically, the implicit cursor of a `FOR` loop is simpler to handle and cheaper:

- [Truncating all tables in a Postgres database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829158/truncating-all-tables-in-a-postgres-database/12082038#12082038)

And most of the time you don't even need any cursors or loops at all. Set-based solutions are typically simpler and faster.