How to use an anonymous record type in an insert or update?
Let's say I have a function that returns type record:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pnh_row(myId integer)
    RETURNS RECORD AS $$
DECLARE
    myRow RECORD;
BEGIN
   // blah blah
    return myRow;
END;
$$ language plpgsql;

How can I insert and update this record into a table (preferably without naming each individual field).
I tried:
insert into mytable select pnh_row(1234);

but I get:
ERROR:  column "id" is of type integer but expression is of type record
LINE 1: insert into mytable select pnh_row(1234);
                                                ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

Ideally, I could also update the whole record from this tuple also, but I can't think what syntax to even try. I guess I could do either one by tediously listing out every column, but is there a way to avoid that?

What columns does "mytable" have, why don't you mention these columns in the INSERT statement, and what columns does the record have that you return? You could use SELECT * FROM pnh_row(1234); but using a * in production code is a bad habit that leads to bugs. Replace it with the correct column names.

Why do you use RETURNS RECORD in the first place? Make that RETURNS mytable, i.e. the row type of the table where you want to insert the data.

@FrankHeikens It's not a "bad habit" in this case, because the table I'm inserting into is by definition what I'm outputing from the function... (think of it like roll your own materialized view, this is the function that keeps the view current). Your suggestion of select * from pnh_row(1234) works, however I wanted to be able to regenerate the whole view based on the set of keys in another table... kinda like select pnh_row(id) from my_other_table;... except that won't work for the same reason. Also it doesn't answer if there's a way to update a row the same way without a list of fields.

@Bergi That seems like a good suggestion, I made that change but it doesn't fully answer the question.

@FrankHeikens ok, it looks like this works:  insert into mytable select pnh.* from my_other_table, pnh_row(my_other_table.id) pnh; ... ideally I'd like to also do updates though.

Returning an anonymous record type is rarely useful. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17281457/939860, https://stackoverflow.com/a/62687780/939860  Most of the time, there is a simpler solution.

It is a bad habit since you have no clue what you're returning or inserting. You're just hoping that both will match. When you're using the complete names and correct data types, you have the guarantee it works, and you don't need "hope" anymore.

@FrankHeikens it's guaranteed in that this function IS THE function, and the only function that creates this table, and if the data types don't match I WANT IT TO FAIL, because that means something is horribly wrong. I DON'T WANT it to muddle it's way through to a fake success.

@ErwinBrandstetter OK, I get it, anonymous records are not a good idea. However that's not the core issue I'm asking about.

It's still the core issue in your question. Either way, I provided a lipstick for your pig below.

If your function returns a record, you must write a column definition list at the call site, there is no way to avoid that. So instead give the function the proper return type, the row type of the table in which you want to insert: RETURNS mytable. Then you can run
INSERT INTO mytable
SELECT *
FROM pnh_row(1234);


OK, but is there a way to update from such a record?

Update what and how? If you don't know (or don't want to specify) any columns, you cannot target a specific row to update.

But no, an UPDATE command always needs to specify the column_names, there is no way to avoid it. If you don't want to hardcode them, you'll need to generate dynamic SQL.

Disclaimer
Like I commented, the best course of action is not to make that function return an anonymous record to begin with. There are typically better options.
If you indeed need a function, here are some related answers:

Function returning a table for given table and column names

How to return multiple rows from PL/pgSQL function?

Refactor a PL/pgSQL function to return the output of various SELECT queries


Solution with cast
INSERT
While stuck with your unfortunate situation, there is a way to make it work without naming each individual field:
Your attempt:
insert into mytable select pnh_row(1234);
... does not work, because the INSERT tries to assign the returned value (the whole anonymous record) to the first column id of mytable (apparently an integer), which raises a type mismatch exception.
You cannot decompose the returned record since, being anonymous, its structure is unknown:
INSERT INTO mytable SELECT (pnh_row(1234)).*;
The manual:

If the function has been defined as returning the record data type,
then an alias or the key word AS must be present, followed by a column
definition list in the form ( column_name data_type [, ... ]). The
column definition list must match the actual number and types of
columns returned by the function.

You would have to tediously list out every column - each followed by its data type - the thing you want to avoid.
You cannot cast it to the row type mytable because there is no registered cast.
INSERT INTO mytable SELECT (pnh_row(1234)::mytable).*;
However, everything can be cast to and from text. So you can use text as stepping stone:
INSERT INTO mytable SELECT (pnh_row(1234)::text::mytable).*;

But decomposing this way results in a separate function call for every nested column.
Instead, move the function call to a subquery to execute it once, and only decompose in the SELECT list:
INSERT INTO my_table
SELECT (my_row).*
FROM   (SELECT pnh_row(123)::text::my_table) t(my_row);

Note the parentheses required to access fields of the composite type in (my_row).*.
Still, casting to text and back adds cost.
Of course, the record type has to match the row type of my_table.
See:

How to avoid multiple function evals with the (func()).* syntax in a query?

UPDATE
You can use similar syntax to avoid a column definition list. While you can omit target column names in an INSERT (only advisable in certain cases like the one at hand), you must spell out target column names in an UPDATE:
UPDATE my_table
SET    col1 = (t.my_row).col1
--   , ... more?
FROM  (SELECT pnh_row(123)::text::my_table) t(my_row)  -- !
WHERE  my_table_id = 123;  -- or whatever?

But you can omit source column names with multiple-column UPDATE syntax:
UPDATE my_table
SET    (my_table_id, col1, col2, ...)  -- ①
     = (SELECT (my_row).* FROM (SELECT pnh_row(123)::text::my_table) t(my_row))  -- !
WHERE  my_table_id = 123;  -- or whatever?

① List target columns for all source columns in matching order!
You could even fetch column names from the system catalog pg_attribute and build the statement dynamically. See:

SQL update fields of one table from fields of another one

But this is getting ridiculous ...
Solution with (temporary) wrapper function
Create once (per session, if temporary):
CREATE OR REPLACE pg_temp.my_wrapper(my_id int, OUT rec my_table)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   rec := pnh_row($1);   -- assignment succeeds (!)
END
$func$;

Queries are simple again:
INSERT INTO my_table
SELECT * FROM  pg_temp.my_wrapper(123);

UPDATE my_table
SET    (my_table_id, col1, col2, ...)
     = (SELECT * FROM pg_temp.my_wrapper(123))
WHERE  my_table_id = 123;  -- or whatever?

See:

Automatic conversion of anonymous records returned from an UDF to well known table-type
How to create a temporary function in PostgreSQL?

