# Create a function that accepts a string and returns multiple rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, set-returning-functions, create-function

I'm being required to create a function that transforms a single column's value based on the user's input. I need some help on the syntax for doing so.

Here is the query I'm currently performing to get the rows:

```
SELECT payment_id, rental_id, amount FROM payment
```

[image]

some pseudocode on what I'm trying to do:

```
function getReport(String currencyType){
    if(currencyType == 'EUR'){

       Multiply the values in the amounts column by 1.16 and append Euros to it
       Return all the rows in the table

    }else if(currencyType == 'RMB'){

       Multiple the values in the amounts column by 6.44 and append RMB to it
       Return all the rows in the table

    }else{

       Do nothing because the default column values are in USD
       Return all the rows in the table

    }
}
```

I've been trying to create one but I'm struggling with the syntax.
Does not work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_data(currency_type text) RETURNS TABLE payment_info AS $$
    CASE currency_type
    WHEN 'EUR' THEN
        SELECT payment_id, rental_id, amount * 1.16 FROM payment;
    WHEN 'RMB' THEN
        SELECT payment_id, rental_id, amount * 6.44 FROM payment;
    WHEN 'USD' THEN
        SELECT payment_id, rental_id, amount FROM payment;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Could someone please help me with the syntax to creating this function?

Comment: You would do well to read [CASE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE). Hint you can't nest the `SELECT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_data(currency_type text) 
RETURNS TABLE  ( payment_id int, rental_id int, amount numeric(5,2) ) 
language plpgsql
as $$
begin 
   return query 
     SELECT b.payment_id, b.rental_id, 
    case 
        when currency_type = 'EUR' then b.amount * 1.16     
        when currency_type = 'RMB' then b.amount * 6.44 
        when currency_type = 'USD' then b.amount 
    end as amount 
    FROM payment b;
end;$$
```

It does return in the form of a table if you use

```
select * from get_data('EUR');
```

Here a demo

[demo in db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=f9fb3cad0cc45844610efa6101428fca)

Comment: Oh I thought RETURNS TABLE would return them as separate columns, but it sent it back as one column with all the values. How would I return it so all 3 columns like in my screenshot above is returned?

Comment: I updated the post with a new demo in db<>fiddle., It does return the records in the form of a table.

Comment: @DIRTYDAVE, did you check my updated db<>fiddle ? it shows the result in the format of a table with columns as you expect. If so, I would appreciate if you upvote and accept the answer, of course if it solves your issue.

Comment: Yeah just tried it and I didn't add an asterisk and only used ```select get_data('EUR');```. It works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: @DIRTYDAVE, you are very welcome ;)

Comment: This raises an error for the ambiguous column names.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, you are right, however the db<>fiddle link contains the right version of the code that works. I forgot to paste it in the answer. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1):

#### Postgres 14 or later

In Postgres 14 or later, I'd suggest the new standard SQL syntax:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_data(_currency_type text DEFAULT 'USD')
  RETURNS TABLE (payment_id int, rental_id int, amount numeric(5,2)) 
  STABLE PARALLEL SAFE
BEGIN ATOMIC
SELECT p.payment_id, p.rental_id
     , CASE _currency_type
          WHEN 'USD' THEN p.amount
          WHEN 'EUR' THEN p.amount * 1.16
          WHEN 'RMB' THEN p.amount * 6.44
FROM   payment p;
END;
```

See:

- [What does BEGIN ATOMIC ... END mean in a Postgresql SQL function / procedure?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/300512/3684)

Most of the below still applies ...

#### Postgres 13 (or any version)

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_data(_currency_type text DEFAULT 'USD')
  RETURNS TABLE  (payment_id int, rental_id int, amount numeric(5,2)) 
  LANGUAGE sql STABLE PARALLEL SAFE AS
$func$
SELECT p.payment_id, p.rental_id
     , CASE _currency_type
          WHEN 'USD' THEN p.amount
          WHEN 'EUR' THEN p.amount * 1.16
          WHEN 'RMB' THEN p.amount * 6.44 
       -- ELSE 1/0 END   -- ??? this purposely raises an exception
FROM   payment p;
$func$;
```

Stick with **`LANGUAGE sql`** (like in your original attempt). There is no need for `LANGUAGE plpgsql` for the simple function - unless you want to add a custom error message or error handling for invalid input ..

See:

- [Difference between language sql and language plpgsql in PostgreSQL functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755468/difference-between-language-sql-and-language-plpgsql-in-postgresql-functions/24771561#24771561)

Use a simpler **switched `CASE`** (like in your original attempt).

- [Display column name with max value between several columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27067014/display-column-name-with-max-value-between-several-columns/27071163#27071163)
- [Simplify nested case when statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23823179/simplify-nested-case-when-statement/23839984#23839984)

Provide an explicit **`ELSE`** branch. ([SQL `CASE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE) defaults to `NULL` if `ELSE` is not spelled out.)

If `payment_info`, featured in your original attempt, is an existing row type matching your desired return type, use a simple **`RETURNS SETOF payment_info`** instead of `RETURNS TABLE(...)`.

It's good style to **table-qualify columns** with possibly **ambiguous names** like demonstrated. (It's *never* a bad idea in any case.)
But it's a *requirement* in a `LANGUAGE plpgsql` function with `RETURNS TABLE ...)` implicitly declaring `OUT` parameters of the same name as table columns. That would raise an exception like:

> ERROR:  column reference "payment_id" is ambiguous

See:

- [INSERT INTO ... RETURNING - ambiguous column reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39261902/insert-into-returning-ambiguous-column-reference/39283973#39283973)
- [How to return result of a SELECT inside a function in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7945932/how-to-return-result-of-a-select-inside-a-function-in-postgresql/7945958#7945958)

Also: **`numeric(5,2)`?** That raises an exception for `amount > 999.99`. Looks like a loaded foot-gun. Just use `numeric` or something like `numeric(20,2)` for the rounding effect.

About **`STABLE`**:

- [How do IMMUTABLE, STABLE and VOLATILE keywords effect behaviour of function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28569415/how-do-immutable-stable-and-volatile-keywords-effect-behaviour-of-function/28573737#28573737)

About **`PARALLEL SAFE`**:

- [When to mark functions as PARALLEL RESTRICTED vs PARALLEL SAFE?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/251274/3684)

**Finally**, as has been cleared up already, to decompose result rows, call with **`SELECT * FROM`**:

```
SELECT * FROM get_data('USD');
```

See:

- [Simple PostgreSQL function to return rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14178470/simple-postgresql-function-to-return-rows/14185387#14185387)
- [PostgreSQL: ERROR: 42601: a column definition list is required for functions returning "record"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605174/postgresql-error-42601-a-column-definition-list-is-required-for-functions-ret/8611675#8611675)

I added an **default value** for the input parameter: `DEFAULT 'USD'`. That's convenient, but totally optional. It documents what's most commonly expected and allows a short call without explicit parameter:

```
SELECT * FROM get_data();
```